# Unable to add android project - ionic( Error - com.couchbase.lite.phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add android platform to my existing ionic project. I am getting the below error.
Failed to restore plugin `com.couchbase.lite.phonegap` from **config.xml**. You might need to try adding it again.

Error:

> Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:

[image: Error Image - Cordova android issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you tried on Android >= 7 which is needed for the couchbaselite plugin.

so you can downgrade to 6 :

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@6
```

But if you need a recent android, you have to apply this Fixes  : https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin/pull/110

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried to add android@6, I am getting the below error.                                          
Android project created with cordova-android@6.4.0
 
Discovered saved plugin "com.couchbase.lite.phonegap". Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "com.couchbase.lite.phonegap" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error

Answer (score 0):

1. remove manually `node-modules` and `package-lock.json (imp*)`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. finally `run npm install`
4. `ionic cordova platform add android`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove the plugin and it's folder:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove couchbase-lite-phonegap-plugin
rm -rf plugins/com.couchbase.lite.phonegap/
```

Also, remove any line in `package.json` using the wrong folder name of `com.couchbase.lite.phonegap`, if you find any.

Then add your android platform as usual, then add the plugin back.

```
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova plugin add couchbase-lite-phonegap-plugin
```

And if you still get any error, repeat the operation using the `cordova --verbose` directly, without `ionic` command. Example:

`cordova plugin add couchbase-lite-phonegap-plugin --verbose`

That command above should tell you exactly what went wrong.